# Passing Authroization token in GET HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, rest, restful-authentication

trying to call REST API using HttpWebReqeust and passing Authroization with userid and password.

I am getting "Authroization" error when i pass the credential in the header, but it worked when i use the NeworkCredential instance. 
what is the reason the two differences?

```
Error Code:
-----------
String encoded = 
   System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-  1").GetBytes("SVVMGSDFMdoc-p" + ":" + "p$nmmnY4fJoH1"));
 request.Headers.Add("Authroization", "Basic "+ encoded);

Working Code:
-------------
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("SVVMGSDFMdoc-  p","p$nmmnY4fJoH1");
```

Comment: `Authroization` is not spelled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add "Authorization" instead of "Authroization"?

Comment: It worked. sorry it is my fault typographical  error.